# IIS Maintenance page for multiple sites

Tags: iis, maintenance

Is it possible to have a single maintenance/holding page for all sites on an IIS server?

I have one server with 30 sites on it for example. I want to do some maintenance to the server itself which will require my shutting down the coldfusion service that runs the sites. During this down time I want to have holding pages set on the sites. But I don't want to have to go switch 30 of them on every time I need to make an upgrade.

Comment: Maybe you could use the http 503 Service Unavailable. I found a few things with google using that and coldfusion. Might see if any of that applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

My work around is that I will create a single site with a maintenance page in IIS, bind all the other domains to it while it is turned off, then switch off the other sites and switch on the maintenance one.